# compare each value of two rdds in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have two rdd. For e.g.

```
employee =    [(31, ['Raffery', 31, 'a', 'b']),
               (33, ['Jones', 33, '1', 'b']),
               (32, ['Heisenberg', 33, 'a', 'b']),
               (37, ['Robinson', 34, 'c', 'cc']),
               (38, ['Smith', 34, 'a', 'b'])]` 

department =   [[(31, ['Raffery', 31, 'c', 'b']),
                 (33, ['Jones', 33, 'a', 'b']),
                 (34, ['Heisenberg', 33, 'a', 'b'])]`
```

I want to compare the elements of the first rdd with the second one for each key:

The output should look like

> 31 and the fault is in the e[1][2]
>
> 33 and the fault is in the e[1][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how strict the output needs to be in exactly that format, but the following should get you almost all of the way:

Use pyspark dataframes:

```
>>> employee = spark.createDataFrame([(31, ['Raffery', 31, 'a', 'b']), (33, ['Jones', 33, '1', 'b']), (32, ['Heisenberg', 33, 'a', 'b'])], ["id_e", "list_e"])
>>> employee.show()
+----+----------------------+
|id_e|list_e                |
+----+----------------------+
|31  |[Raffery, 31, a, b]   |
|33  |[Jones, 33, 1, b]     |
|32  |[Heisenberg, 33, a, b]|
+----+----------------------+

>>> department = spark.createDataFrame([(31, ['Raffery', 31, 'c', 'b']), (33, ['Jones', 33, 'a', 'b']), (34, ['Heisenberg', 33, 'a', 'b'])], ["id_d", "list_d"])
>>> department.show()
+----+----------------------+
|id_d|list_d                |
+----+----------------------+
|31  |[Raffery, 31, c, b]   |
|33  |[Jones, 33, a, b]     |
|34  |[Heisenberg, 33, a, b]|
+----+----------------------+
```

Join these on, what I assume, are the user ids:

```
>>> joined = employee.join(department, employee.id_e == department.id_d)
>>> joined.show()
+----+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|id_e|             list_e|id_d|             list_d|
+----+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|  31|[Raffery, 31, a, b]|  31|[Raffery, 31, c, b]|
|  33|  [Jones, 33, 1, b]|  33|  [Jones, 33, a, b]|
+----+-------------------+----+-------------------+
```

Then map the indices of the user lists of elements that are not shared between dataframes:

```
>>> joined.rdd.map(lambda row: (row.id_e, [i for i in range(4) if row.list_d[i] != row.list_e[i]])).collect()
[(31, [2]), (33, [2])]
```

Hope that 'll get you on your way, good luck.